# Given that an integral containing $|x_{n}|$ is bounded by a constant, show that $x_{n}\to x$ in $L^{1}(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, lipschitz-functions

This question is related to another question I asked [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748692/show-that-a-sequence-of-uniformly-bounded-continuous-functions-with-lipschitz-co).

For reference, this is the relevant part of that question:

> **Let the sequence of continuous functions $\mathbf{\{x_{n}(t) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}}$, $\mathbf{0 \leq t < \infty}$ be uniformly bounded on $\mathbf{t \in [0, \infty)}$ and on each bounded interval $\mathbf{[0,A]}$ also satisfy the Lipschitz condition:  $\mathbf{\forall t_{1}, t_{2} \in [0,A]}$, $\mathbf{|x_{n}(t_{1})-x_{n}(t_{2})|\leq L_{A} |t_{1}-t_{2}|}$, where the Lipschitz constant $\mathbf{L_{A}}$ is independent of the index $n \geq 1$ but depends on $A$.**

In that other problem, I showed that the sequence $x_{n}$ was pre-compact (meaning its closure is compact) in the space of bounded continuous functions $C_{B}[0, \infty)$ with the supremum norm, and thus has a limit point $x \in C_{B}[0, \infty)$.

**Now, in addition to those conditions, suppose that, $\exists \alpha > 0$ such that $\forall n$, $\mathbf{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha}|x_{n}(t)|dt \leq \text{constant}}$.**

**I need to prove that $\mathbf{x_{n}\to x}$ in $\mathbf{L^{1}(0,\infty)}$ as $\mathbf{n\to \infty}$.**

I suppose that I should consider the norm of the difference of $x_{n}-x$ in $L^{1}(0, \infty)$ of the integral from $0$ to $\infty$, and split the interval into two parts. How to do that, however, is part of my problem: I was given the hint to choose my interval in terms of small $\epsilon$, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

I really have no idea how to put all of this together. I've been playing around with this for days and am still no closer to coming up with a proof.

Please help.

,

Comment: Answered in the previous question.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, what do you mean? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: I mean in the question you have posted above as your "earlier" question. I haven't answered this one yet, I'll get around it sometime.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, that's too bad - this one was the one I was really struggling with! LOL.

Comment: Ok, I'll answer this one. I''m hoping that the constant bounding the integral does not depend on ANY of the factors above.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, I don't think it does. I think it's just supposed to help us split up the integral/show it converges.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, I think we also need to use the fact that it's lipschitz on $[0,A]$? But I'm not sure.

Comment: You seem to be correct, however I am having the same problem as you, so I'll attempt to get over it. If you do, then do inform me.

Comment: @DanielFischer, could you help at all?

Comment: @robjohn, you also are extremely knowledgeable about this sort of thing. Could you offer me any assistance?

Comment: Probably the assumption that $\int_0^{\infty} t^{\alpha} \lvert x_n(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant C$ independent of $n$ gives you that the $x_n$ are "uniformly small on the tails", for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $A(\varepsilon)$ such that $\int_{A(\varepsilon)}^{\infty} \lvert x_n(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $n$. Then the uniform convergence on $[0,A(\varepsilon)]$ gives you an $N$ with $\int_0^{A(\varepsilon)} \lvert x_n(t) - x(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant \varepsilon$
for $n \geqslant N$ and that gets you $\lVert x_n - x\rVert_{L^1} \leqslant 2\varepsilon$ for $n \geqslant N$.

Comment: For $\alpha > 1$, it's straightforward, I think, but for $0 < \alpha \leqslant 1$, the details may be a bit hairier.
Ah, no, it's straightforward for any $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, can you explain a little bit more why the assumption that that integral is bounded by a constant independent of $n$ gives us that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists A(\epsilon)$ s.t. $\int_{A(\epsilon)}^{\infty}|x_{n}(t)|dt \leq \epsilon$ for all $n$? Also, how the cases differ when $\alpha >1$ as opposed to when $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assert that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges in $L^1(0,\infty)$, we should require that the sequence is pointwise convergent (and by Ascoli, it is then locally uniformly convergent), otherwise sequences like $x_n(t) = (-1)^n\cdot f(t)$ for a nonzero $f$ give counterexamples. So either we strengthen the hypothesis and require that the full sequence is pointwise/locally uniformly convergent, or we weaken the conclusion and only state that a subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges in $L^1(0,\infty)$. Both ways are equivalent, the only difference is whether we extract a convergent subsequence before or after we state the proposition. Let's extract the subsequence before, and hence assume that $x_n \to x$ locally uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

From the premise that there is an $\alpha > 0$ and a $C \in (0,\infty)$ such that

$$\int_0^{\infty} t^{\alpha}\lvert x_n(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant C\tag{1}$$

for all $n$, the uniform boundedness of the sequence $(x_n)$ and the pointwise convergence, we obtain (via the dominated convergence theorem for example) that also

$$\int_0^{\infty} t^{\alpha} \lvert x(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant C,$$

with the same $\alpha$ and $C$.

The function $t \mapsto t^{\alpha}$ is monotonically increasing, hence, for every $n$ and $A\in (0,\infty)$ we have

$$C \geqslant \int_A^{\infty} t^{\alpha}\lvert x_n(t)\rvert\,dt \geqslant A^{\alpha} \int_A^{\infty} \lvert x_n(t)\rvert\,dt,\tag{2}$$

and the same inequality holds for the limit function $x$. Thus

\begin{align}
\lVert x_n - x\rVert_{L^1(0,\infty)} &= \int_0^{\infty} \lvert x_n(t) - x(t)\rvert\,dt \\
&= \int_0^A \lvert x_n(t) - x(t)\rvert\,dt + \int_A^{\infty} \lvert x_n(t) - x(t)\rvert\,dt \\
&\leqslant \int_0^A \lvert x_n(t) - x(t)\rvert\,dt + \int_A^{\infty} \lvert x_n(t)\rvert\,dt + \int_A^{\infty} \lvert x(t)\rvert\,dt\\
&\leqslant \int_0^A \lvert x_n(t) - x(t)\rvert\,dt + 2\cdot C \cdot A^{-\alpha}. \tag{by (2)}
\end{align}

Now, given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $A \in (0,\infty)$ so that $2\cdot C\cdot A^{-\alpha} < \varepsilon/2$, and then use the locally uniform convergence of $(x_n)$ to $x$ to find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sup \{ \lvert x_n(t) - x(t)\rvert : t \in [0,A]\} \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2A}$$

for all $n \geqslant N$. Then $\lVert x_n - x\rVert_{L^1(0,\infty)} < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geqslant N$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we have shown that $x_n \to x$ in $L^1(0,\infty)$.

Comment: how do you know$t^{\alpha}$ is monotonically increasing?

Comment: Because $\alpha > 0$. $\log$ is increasing, so for $\alpha > 0$ also $t \mapsto \alpha\cdot \log t$ is increasing. $\exp$ is increasing, so $t \mapsto \exp(\alpha\cdot \log t)$ is increasing. But $t^{\alpha} = \exp(\alpha\log t)$.